# What are the best free reporting tools?

Tags: visualization, data-cleaning

What are the best free Business Intelligence (**Reporting**) tools, that allows live updates on the reports and also sharing them to other users? 
Actually now I’m using the community edition of **Pentaho** but it’s limited in the number of output rows in the process of reporting. Please I need your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: I recommend R shiny

Comment: Thank you for the respond, do you have some other suggestions, in fact I don't wanna build a webapp from scratch! I'm looking for something ready to implement.